# Flex formatting full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a calorie calculator and I ran into some trouble with the FLEX css display property. Thing is I'm trying to make the column on the right full height, but I can't, what is wrong with my CSS?

Thanks!

P.S. You might have to click on one of the items for the right part to show up because of the js. And don't worry about any other formatting issues, it's not responsive yet.

Thanks!

```
    <div id="wrapper">

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
  <li class="bases"></li>
  <li class="flex-steps base">BASES</li> 
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="517.2" data-carbs="76.1" data-fat="14.4" data-proteins="20.8"  vegetarian glutenfree weightloss lactosefree vegan>RICE NOODLES</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="510.5" data-carbs="66.1" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="29.8" vegetarian lactosefree>EGG NOODLES</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="506.9" data-carbs="76.9" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="18.1" vegetarian lactosefree >VERMICELLI</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="476.6" data-carbs="53.8" data-fat="16.6" data-proteins="28" vegetarian lactosefree>WHOLE GRAIN NOODLES</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="514.8" data-carbs="72.4" data-fat="14.8" data-proteins="23" vegetarian>WHITE RICE</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="516" data-carbs="70.1" data-fat="16" data-proteins="22.9" glutenfree vegetarian>BROWN RICE</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="106.6" data-carbs="14.2" data-fat="1.8" data-proteins="8.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>VEGETABLE BASE</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="flex-container-column">
  <li class="meats"></li>
  <li class="flex-steps meat">MEATS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="65.9" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="1.5" data-proteins="12.9" lactosefree glutenfree>CHICKEN</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="166.4" data-carbs="0.1" data-fat="14" data-proteins="10" glutenfree lactosefree>PORK</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="50.1" data-carbs="0.4" data-fat="2.9" data-proteins="5.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SMOKED TOFU</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="120.8" data-carbs="0.3" data-fat="8.4" data-proteins="11" glutenfree lactosefree>BEEF</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="111.2" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="7.2" data-proteins="11.4" glutenfree lactosefree>DUCK</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="107.5" data-carbs="2.4" data-fat="1.1" data-proteins="22" glutenfree lactosefree>PRAWNS</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="flex-container-column">
  <li class="toppings"></li>
  <li class="flex-steps topping">TOPPINGS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.3" data-carbs="1.2" data-fat="0.1" data-proteins="1.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>VEGETABLE MIX</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="160" data-carbs="9" data-fat="12" data-proteins="4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CASHEWS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.2" data-carbs="2.5" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.3" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SWEET PEPPERS MIX</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11" data-carbs="1.8" data-fat="0.2" data-proteins="0.5" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>WOOD EAR MUSHROOMS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="10.8" data-carbs="1" data-fat="0" data-proteins="1.7" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>MUSHROOM</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="19.6" data-carbs="4.8" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>PINEAPPLE</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="3.2" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BAMBOO SHOOTS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="7.2" data-carbs="1" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.8" glutenfree vegetarian vegan lactosefree>CHINESE CABBAGE</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="flex-container-column">
  <li class="sauces"></li>
  <li class="flex-steps sauce">SAUCES</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="15" data-carbs="2.3" data-fat="0.6" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree lactosefree>THAILAND-PADTHAI</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="9.2" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CHINESE SWEET & SOUR</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="9.8" data-carbs="0.9" data-fat="0.6" data-proteins="0.2" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BURMA-GREEN CURRY</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="15.3" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="0.9" data-proteins="0.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>INDONESIA-SATAY</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.5" data-carbs="1.2" data-fat="0.7" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree lactosefree>LAOSZ-RED CURRY</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="7.2" data-carbs="1.3" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.5" lactosefree>JAPAN-TERIYAKI</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="flex-container-column">
  <li class="extratoppings"></li>
  <li class="flex-steps">EXTRA TOPPINGS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="145.9" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="12.3" data-proteins="6.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>ROASTED PEANUTS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="14.6" data-carbs="3" data-fat="0.2" data-proteins="0.2" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CORIANDER</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="95" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="8.2" data-proteins="3.9" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SESAME SEEDS</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="32.3" data-carbs="6" data-fat="0.3" data-proteins="1.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BASIL</li>
  <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="0.1" data-fat="12.46" data-proteins="1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>COCONUT CHIPS</li>
</ul>
  

 
  
</div>  

<div class="summary" style="display:block;opacity:0;">
  
<div id="totalCalories">Total Calories: <span id="total"></span></div>  
<div id="totalCalories1">Total Carbs: <span id="totalCarbs"></span></div>
<span id="totalCalories1">Total Fat:</span> <span id="totalFats"></span> 
<span id="totalCalories1">Total Protein: <span id="totalProteins"></span></span>

                <br>
                <img id="typeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                
                <img id="glutenFreeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                <img id="vegetarianImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                <img id="typeImageWeightLoss" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                <img id="veganImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                <img id="lactoseFreeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
                <br>
                
                <div id="vegan"></div>
                <div id="glutenFree"></div>
                <div id="typeVegetarian"></div>
                <div id="typeWeightLoss"></div>
                <div id="vegetarian"></div>
                <div id="lactoseFree"></div>
            </span>

        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>


#wrapper {width:100%;}
#total {width:30%; 
  height:100%;
  background: #424040;


}


body {background: #f3f3f3 url(http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/whiteback.jpg);}

.bases {background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bases.png") center no-repeat;height:170px; width:210px; list-style-type: none;opacity:0;}

.meats {background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/toppings.png") center no-repeat;height:170px; width:210px; list-style-type: none;opacity:0;}

.toppings {background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/toppings.png") center no-repeat;height:170px; width:210px; list-style-type: none; opacity:0;}
 
.sauces {background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sauces.png") center no-repeat;height:170px; width:210px; list-style-type: none;opacity:0;}

.extratoppings {background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sauces.png") center no-repeat;height:170px; width:210px; list-style-type: none; opacity:0;}




.flex-container-column {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Safari */
  flex-wrap:         nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari */
  justify-content:         space-between;
  float:left;
  margin:0px;
}

.flex-steps {
  background:;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #424040;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:"lithos pro";
  font-weight:700;
  
}

.flex-item {
  background: #424040;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family:"lithos pro";
  font-weight:300;
  
}

.flex-item:hover {
  background: #6FC0BB;
}

.clicked {
  background: #6FC0BB;
  
}


//* fonts *//
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro Black';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Li Pro Black'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Black.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Lithos Pro Regular'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two Italic';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: local('Lobster Two Italic'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LobsterTwo-Italic.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Condensed Light.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url ('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin Italic.otf');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

.summary {

  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding:5%;
  color:white;
  margin-left:75%;
  padding-top:15;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#f3f3f3 url(http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/greyback.jpg); 
  
}

#totalCalories {margin-top:70%; 
  font-size:1.2em; 
  color: #424040;   
  color:white;
  font-family: "Lobster Two";}
#totalCalories1 {
  margin-top:3%; 
  font-size:1em; 
  color: #424040;}

/* RESPONSIVE */

/* 1440 media */

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
  
  .flex-container-column {
  margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
}

.flex-steps {

  padding: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:700;
  
}

.flex-item {
  
  padding: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
  
  
}

 .total {
  color:white;
  font-family: "Lobster Two";
  font-size: 1.3em;
  background: #424040;
  
  
  }
 
  
  #totFat {
    display:block;
    line-height:0;
  
  }
  
  
  
}



 $(document).ready(function() {
      
      $('.bases').css("opacity", 0);
      $('.meats').css("opacity", 0);
      $('.sauces').css("opacity", 0);
      $('.bases').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
      $('.meats').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
      $('.sauces').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
      $('.summary').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
      });



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
    var calories = $(this).data('calories');
    var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
    var fat = $(this).data('fat');
    var proteins = $(this).data('proteins');
    var totalNum = $('#total');
    var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
    var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
    var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
    var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
    var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
    var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
    var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

    if (pressed) {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
      totalNum.text(+(currentCalories - calories).toFixed(1)); 
      totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs - carbs).toFixed(1));
      totalFats.text(+(currentFats - fat).toFixed(1));
      totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins - proteins).toFixed(1));
      
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      totalNum.text(+(currentCalories + calories).toFixed(1)); 
      totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs + carbs).toFixed(1)); 
      totalFats.text(+(currentFats + fat).toFixed(1)); 
      totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins + proteins).toFixed(1));
    }


    
    // vegan      
    var vegan = false;
    var vegetarian = false;
    var glutenfree = false;
    var lactosefree = false;
    var weightloss = false;
    
    //Vegan
    
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") {
        vegan = true;
      } else {
        vegan = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegan) {
      $('#vegan').text("Ez az összeállítás Vegán");
      $('#veganImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#veganImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/vegan2.png");
      $('#veganImage').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
    } else {
      $('#vegan').text("");
      $('#veganImage').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    }
    
  //Glutenfree  
    
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined") {
        glutenfree = true;
      } else {
        glutenfree = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (glutenfree) {
      $('#glutenFree').text("Ez az összeállítás gluténmentes");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#glutenFreeImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/glutenfree-1.png");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
    } else {
      $('#glutenFree').text("");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    }

 //Vegetarian   
    
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegetarian") != "undefined") {
        vegetarian = true;
      } else {
        vegetarian = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegetarian) {
      $('#vegetarian').fadeIn(3000);
      $('#vegetarian').text("Ez az összeállítás vegetáriánus");
      $('#vegetarianImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#vegetarianImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/vegetarian.png");
      $('#vegetarianImage').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
    } else {
      $('#vegetarian').text("");
      $('#vegetarianImage').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    }
    
  //Weightloss  
    
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("weightloss") != "undefined") {
        weightloss = true;
      } else {
        weightloss = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (weightloss) {
      $('#typeWeightLoss').text("This bowl is considered to be low-calorie!");
      $('#typeImageLactoseFree').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#typeImageWeightloss').fadeIn("slow");
      $('#typeImageWeightloss').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
      $('#typeWeightLoss').text("");
      $('#typeImageWeightLoss').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    }
    
//Lactosefree 
    
$(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("lactosefree") != "undefined") {
        lactosefree = true;
      } else {
        lactosefree = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (lactosefree) {
      $('#lactoseFree').text("Ez az összeállítás LactoseFree");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Lactose-free.png");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
    } else {
      $('#lactoseFree').text("");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    }
        
  

  });
  
});

// Gluten-free esetén alapszósz és szójaszósz nélkül! Barna rizs glut free?//

// Vegetáriánus - Base sauce nélkül! A levesek nem vegák. Tojás nélkül!!!//
```

Comment: try to add height of 100% to the <html> and <body> tag

Comment: You are suppose to post a _minimal_ working code snippet, not _all_ the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You were missing height of 100% on the parent elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.bases').css("opacity", 0);
  $('.meats').css("opacity", 0);
  $('.sauces').css("opacity", 0);
  $('.bases').fadeTo(1000, 1);
  $('.meats').fadeTo(1000, 1);
  $('.sauces').fadeTo(1000, 1);
  $('.summary').fadeTo(1000, 1);
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
    var calories = $(this).data('calories');
    var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
    var fat = $(this).data('fat');
    var proteins = $(this).data('proteins');
    var totalNum = $('#total');
    var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
    var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
    var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
    var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
    var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
    var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
    var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

    if (pressed) {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
      totalNum.text(+(currentCalories - calories).toFixed(1));
      totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs - carbs).toFixed(1));
      totalFats.text(+(currentFats - fat).toFixed(1));
      totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins - proteins).toFixed(1));

    } else {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      totalNum.text(+(currentCalories + calories).toFixed(1));
      totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs + carbs).toFixed(1));
      totalFats.text(+(currentFats + fat).toFixed(1));
      totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins + proteins).toFixed(1));
    }



    // vegan      
    var vegan = false;
    var vegetarian = false;
    var glutenfree = false;
    var lactosefree = false;
    var weightloss = false;

    //Vegan

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") {
        vegan = true;
      } else {
        vegan = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegan) {
      $('#vegan').text("Ez az összeállítás Vegán");
      $('#veganImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#veganImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/vegan2.png");
      $('#veganImage').fadeTo(1000, 1);
    } else {
      $('#vegan').text("");
      $('#veganImage').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    }

    //Glutenfree  

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("glutenfree") != "undefined") {
        glutenfree = true;
      } else {
        glutenfree = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (glutenfree) {
      $('#glutenFree').text("Ez az összeállítás gluténmentes");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#glutenFreeImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/glutenfree-1.png");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').fadeTo(1000, 1);
    } else {
      $('#glutenFree').text("");
      $('#glutenFreeImage').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    }

    //Vegetarian   

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegetarian") != "undefined") {
        vegetarian = true;
      } else {
        vegetarian = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegetarian) {
      $('#vegetarian').fadeIn(3000);
      $('#vegetarian').text("Ez az összeállítás vegetáriánus");
      $('#vegetarianImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#vegetarianImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/vegetarian.png");
      $('#vegetarianImage').fadeTo(1000, 1);
    } else {
      $('#vegetarian').text("");
      $('#vegetarianImage').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    }

    //Weightloss  

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("weightloss") != "undefined") {
        weightloss = true;
      } else {
        weightloss = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (weightloss) {
      $('#typeWeightLoss').text("This bowl is considered to be low-calorie!");
      $('#typeImageLactoseFree').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#typeImageWeightloss').fadeIn("slow");
      $('#typeImageWeightloss').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
      $('#typeWeightLoss').text("");
      $('#typeImageWeightLoss').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    }

    //Lactosefree 

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("lactosefree") != "undefined") {
        lactosefree = true;
      } else {
        lactosefree = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (lactosefree) {
      $('#lactoseFree').text("Ez az összeállítás LactoseFree");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').css("opacity", 0);
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').attr("src", "http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Lactose-free.png");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').fadeTo(1000, 1);
    } else {
      $('#lactoseFree').text("");
      $('#lactoseFreeImage').fadeTo(1000, 0);
    }



  });

});

// Gluten-free esetén alapszósz és szójaszósz nélkül! Barna rizs glut free?//

// Vegetáriánus - Base sauce nélkül! A levesek nem vegák. Tojás nélkül!!!//
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#total {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #424040;
}

body {
  background: #f3f3f3 url(http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/whiteback.jpg);
}

.bases {
  background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bases.png") center no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.meats {
  background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/toppings.png") center no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.toppings {
  background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/toppings.png") center no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.sauces {
  background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sauces.png") center no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.extratoppings {
  background: url("http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sauces.png") center no-repeat;
  height: 170px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.flex-container-column {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  /* Safari */
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /* Safari */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  /* Safari */
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}

.flex-steps {
  background: ;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #424040;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "lithos pro";
  font-weight: 700;
}

.flex-item {
  background: #424040;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: "lithos pro";
  font-weight: 300;
}

.flex-item:hover {
  background: #6FC0BB;
}

.clicked {
  background: #6FC0BB;
}

//* fonts *//
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lithos Pro Black';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Li Pro Black'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Black.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lithos Pro Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Lithos Pro Regular'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two Italic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Lobster Two Italic'), url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LobsterTwo-Italic.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Condensed Light.otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url ('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin Italic.otf');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url('https://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}

.summary {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 5%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 75%;
  padding-top: 15;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f3f3f3 url(http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/greyback.jpg);
}

#totalCalories {
  margin-top: 70%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #424040;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lobster Two";
}

#totalCalories1 {
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #424040;
}


/* RESPONSIVE */


/* 1440 media */

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .flex-container-column {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .flex-steps {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .flex-item {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .total {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Lobster Two";
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background: #424040;
  }
  #totFat {
    display: block;
    line-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
    <li class="bases"></li>
    <li class="flex-steps base">BASES</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="517.2" data-carbs="76.1" data-fat="14.4" data-proteins="20.8" vegetarian glutenfree weightloss lactosefree vegan>RICE NOODLES</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="510.5" data-carbs="66.1" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="29.8" vegetarian lactosefree>EGG NOODLES</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="506.9" data-carbs="76.9" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="18.1" vegetarian lactosefree>VERMICELLI</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="476.6" data-carbs="53.8" data-fat="16.6" data-proteins="28" vegetarian lactosefree>WHOLE GRAIN NOODLES</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="514.8" data-carbs="72.4" data-fat="14.8" data-proteins="23" vegetarian>WHITE RICE</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="516" data-carbs="70.1" data-fat="16" data-proteins="22.9" glutenfree vegetarian>BROWN RICE</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="106.6" data-carbs="14.2" data-fat="1.8" data-proteins="8.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>VEGETABLE BASE</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
    <li class="meats"></li>
    <li class="flex-steps meat">MEATS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="65.9" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="1.5" data-proteins="12.9" lactosefree glutenfree>CHICKEN</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="166.4" data-carbs="0.1" data-fat="14" data-proteins="10" glutenfree lactosefree>PORK</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="50.1" data-carbs="0.4" data-fat="2.9" data-proteins="5.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SMOKED TOFU</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="120.8" data-carbs="0.3" data-fat="8.4" data-proteins="11" glutenfree lactosefree>BEEF</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="111.2" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="7.2" data-proteins="11.4" glutenfree lactosefree>DUCK</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="107.5" data-carbs="2.4" data-fat="1.1" data-proteins="22" glutenfree lactosefree>PRAWNS</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
    <li class="toppings"></li>
    <li class="flex-steps topping">TOPPINGS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.3" data-carbs="1.2" data-fat="0.1" data-proteins="1.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>VEGETABLE MIX</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="160" data-carbs="9" data-fat="12" data-proteins="4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CASHEWS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.2" data-carbs="2.5" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.3" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SWEET PEPPERS MIX</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11" data-carbs="1.8" data-fat="0.2" data-proteins="0.5" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>WOOD EAR MUSHROOMS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="10.8" data-carbs="1" data-fat="0" data-proteins="1.7" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>MUSHROOM</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="19.6" data-carbs="4.8" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>PINEAPPLE</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="3.2" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BAMBOO SHOOTS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="7.2" data-carbs="1" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.8" glutenfree vegetarian vegan lactosefree>CHINESE CABBAGE</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
    <li class="sauces"></li>
    <li class="flex-steps sauce">SAUCES</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="15" data-carbs="2.3" data-fat="0.6" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree lactosefree>THAILAND-PADTHAI</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="9.2" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CHINESE SWEET & SOUR</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="9.8" data-carbs="0.9" data-fat="0.6" data-proteins="0.2" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BURMA-GREEN CURRY</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="15.3" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="0.9" data-proteins="0.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>INDONESIA-SATAY</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="11.5" data-carbs="1.2" data-fat="0.7" data-proteins="0.1" glutenfree lactosefree>LAOSZ-RED CURRY</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="7.2" data-carbs="1.3" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.5" lactosefree>JAPAN-TERIYAKI</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="flex-container-column">
    <li class="extratoppings"></li>
    <li class="flex-steps">EXTRA TOPPINGS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="145.9" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="12.3" data-proteins="6.6" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>ROASTED PEANUTS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="14.6" data-carbs="3" data-fat="0.2" data-proteins="0.2" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>CORIANDER</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="95" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="8.2" data-proteins="3.9" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>SESAME SEEDS</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="32.3" data-carbs="6" data-fat="0.3" data-proteins="1.4" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>BASIL</li>
    <li class="flex-item ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="0.1" data-fat="12.46" data-proteins="1" glutenfree vegetarian lactosefree>COCONUT CHIPS</li>
  </ul>




</div>

<div class="summary" style="display:block;opacity:0;">

  <div id="totalCalories">Total Calories: <span id="total"></span></div>
  <div id="totalCalories1">Total Carbs: <span id="totalCarbs"></span></div>
  <span id="totalCalories1">Total Fat:</span> <span id="totalFats"></span>
  <span id="totalCalories1">Total Protein: <span id="totalProteins"></span></span>

  <br>
  <img id="typeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />

  <img id="glutenFreeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
  <img id="vegetarianImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
  <img id="typeImageWeightLoss" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
  <img id="veganImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
  <img id="lactoseFreeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="" />
  <br>

  <div id="vegan"></div>
  <div id="glutenFree"></div>
  <div id="typeVegetarian"></div>
  <div id="typeWeightLoss"></div>
  <div id="vegetarian"></div>
  <div id="lactoseFree"></div>
  </span>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: A code dump is useless, explain what you did to make it work. When done, let me know and I retract my downvote.

Comment: the problem is not in my code it is in the responsiveness, go to the full page version of my code and you will see the height 100% on the right nav... I just solved the problem he asked about the right nav not being 100% in height and the problem was that the parent elements were not having the full page width so I added height of 100% to the html and body tag which led to the full height on right column.

Comment: You should add _"an explanation what you did to make it work"_ within the answer, not as a comment

Comment: I replied to his post as a comment and I thought he would know it as that is the first line on my CSS code but I just edited my post, hope you get the point

Comment: An answer should _always_ have an explanation, retracted my downvote.

Comment: Thank you so much. It almost works perfectly, however, there's a small gap at the top and at the side. Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8znqw82x0ykxsr/Screenshot%202017-11-08%2009.24.07.png?dl=0 any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: body has a margin of 8px for some reason, so you can add body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; } in your CSS